# Increase the size of the bitmap when zooming

Tags: android, bitmap, zooming, overlays

I have a class that handles the drawing bitmaps on a map and the problem is that when you zoom out the image gets larger and as it approaches becomes smaller. I want to do just the opposite, that when you approach gets bigger and when you leave gets smaller.

i put the painting class objects:

```
public class OverlayMapa extends Overlay {

private Double latitud = 40.654722 * 1E6;
private Double longitud = -4.694444 * 1E6;

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
    {
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitud.intValue(), longitud.intValue());
        GeoPoint picture = new GeoPoint(latitud.intValue(),longitud.intValue());
        int zoom = mapView.getZoomLevel();

        if (shadow == false)
        {
            Point centro = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(geoPoint, centro);

            Point pPicture = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(picture, pPicture);

            Bitmap bmPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapView.getResources(), R.drawable.picture);

            if(zoom == 21)
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmPicture, 293, 173, false);
            if(zoom == 20)
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmPicture, 260, 150, false);
            if(zoom == 19)
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmPicture, 229, 126, false);
            if(zoom == 18)
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmPicture, 200, 100, false);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmPicture, pPicture.x - (bmPicture.getWidth()/2),pPicture.y - (bmPicture.getHeight()/2), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're explicitly using set dimensions(ie 293x173). Just change them to suit your needs.

Comment: Also, you're not even using the return of `createScaledBitmap()`. It doesn't do an in-place scale, you need another `Bitmap` object.

Comment: Umm just saw the failure of what not to use the return value of the function bitmap scaladed, but is not there an automatic way to do that will make it larger zoom?
For example, when the zoom is 15 drawing up much more space than you should, but when the zoom is 21, it is very small ... Can not put anything to do otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not entirely sure what you're going for. Maybe a screenshot or diagram of exactly what you're getting/wanting would help out.

Comment: for example, when the zoom value is 15, the picture has a big size,imagine 400 x 400, and this picture occupies a large portion of map, if i press the zoom botton, the zoom value get 21, the picture has a small size, imagine 200x200 and this picture occupies a short portion of map.The best would be to occupy a certain real meter map, so if we increase the zoom level will resize the image occupying the fair share

Comment: I tried to use a new bitmap but does not work:                  if(zoom == 21)
{
   Bitmap bmPicture21 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmPicture, 293, 173, true);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmPicture21, pPicture.x - (bmPicture21.getWidth()/2),pPicture.y - (bmPicture21.getHeight()/2), null);

Comment: attached two photos, the first([link](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-20130219181756-8309235.html)) is seen as by far the huddle painted elements, and the second( [link](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-20130219181918-8309238.html)) looks like when you zoom in very little space map